# Evaluating sums with spherical Bessel functions

Tags: numerics, special-functions, summation

I'm running Mathematica 13.0, student edition, on Windows. In physics, the total scattering cross-section of plane waves off a hard sphere of radius $1$ is

$$\sigma(k) = \frac{4 \pi}{k^2} \sum_{l=0}^\infty (2l+1) \left|\frac{j_l(k)}{h_l(k)}  \right|^2$$

where $j_l$ is a [spherical Bessel function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and $h_l$ is a [spherical Hankel function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalHankelFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), both of the first kind.

I am hoping to evaluate this in Mathematica and to make a plot of $\sigma(k)$ against $k$ from $.1$ to $20$. However, I'm running into serious difficulties - Mathematica seems to hang, even if I truncate the upper limit of the sum from $\infty$ down to just $30$.

For example, for $k=1$,

```
SBJ = SphericalBesselJ;
SH1 = SphericalHankelH1;
(4 Pi)/1^2 NSum[(2 l + 1) Abs[SBJ[l, 1]/SH1[l, 1]]^2, {l, 0, 30}]
```

hangs for a quite long time before spitting the error "Summand (or its derivative) [complicated expression for summand] is not numerical at point l=15".

Truncating the upper limit to just $10$ seems to run instantaneously, but I expect that to give a poor approximation at larger values of $k$; $k=20$, say.

I was under the impression that spherical Bessel and Hankel functions are actually rather simple - for example, $h_0(k) = -i \frac{e^{ik}}{k}$, $h_1(k) = (-\frac{i}{k^2}-\frac{1}{k})e^{ik}$, and so on. That is, the Hankel functions are just complex exponentials multiplying complex polynomials in $\frac{1}{k}$. I could see trouble brewing for small $k$, but above I was taking $k=1$.

---

What's causing the massive slowdown in calculating the sum, even when truncating the upper bound of the sum to a small value like $l_{max}=30$? How might I speed this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed `Abs[...]^2` to `... Conjugate[...]` and `NSum` to `Sum[...]//N`

```
SBJ = SphericalBesselJ;
SH1 = SphericalHankelH1;
(4 Pi)/1^2   Sum[(2 l + 1)  # Conjugate[#] &[SBJ[l, 1]/SH1[l, 1]] , {l, 0, 30}] // N
(*10.6262 + 4.36409*10^-17 I*)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this exactly solved my hanging issue, and I've now got a nice plot that fits with my rough intuition (decays from $4\pi$ to $2\pi$). Is there an easy way to see why this was so helpful?

Comment: @user196574 Thanks! Very often `Abs[]` shows numerically problems, that's why I try to avoid if possible. Don't know why `NSum` fails.

Answer (score 4):

Abs is no problem, if you avoid interpolation of NSum and calculate NSum at the exact integer l values with the help of `NSumTerms` .

```
SBJ = SphericalBesselJ;
SH1 = SphericalHankelH1;
(4 Pi)/1^2 NSum[(2 l + 1) Abs[SBJ[l, 1]/SH1[l, 1]]^2, {l, 0, 30}, 
  NSumTerms -> 31]

(*   10.6262   *)
```

Comment: Interesting.  Why was there interpolation happening for a finite sum in the first place?  That seems to be bad in every case I can think of.

Comment: `NSum` only provides an approximation. "By default NSum uses 15 terms at the beginning before approximating the tail." If the tail is not sufficiently well-behaved, additional terms are required using the option `NSumTerms` ("number of terms to use before extrapolation"). The behavior of the tail is tested by observing the effect of varying the value of `NSumTerms`.

Comment: @BobHanlon , NSum provides an aproximation for infinite sums or, if NSumTerms is lower than terms for finite sums. With l from 0 to 30 und NSumTerms =31, there is no tail. Regard `rp = Reap[
   NSum[(2 l + 1) Abs[SBJ[l, 1]/SH1[l, 1]]^2, {l, 0, 30}, 
    NSumTerms -> 31, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[l]]][[2, 1]]` which gives all integer l.

Comment: Not quite shure anymore, but in this cases does:  {0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., \
15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 28., \
29., 30.}

Comment: @Akku14 - Look at `ListPlot[Block[{k = 0}, NSum[ 1/(n + 1), {n, 0, 30}, NSumTerms -> #, EvaluationMonitor :> k++]; {#, k}] & /@ Range[15, 30], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {NSumTerms, "Number of terms"}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon ,  my aim was to create (pseudo) integer values for n, where `Abs[SBJ[l, 1]/SH1[l, 1]]^2` has no problems. This can be achieved in any case for NSumTerms ==nmax+1. Follwing example shows, it also can be achieved for j >=22, but to force NSum take j==31 or greater. The number of evaluations is not relevant to evaluate the given Abs, but the values of n itself. See  `(tab = Table[{j, 
     Reap[NSum[1/(n + 1), {n, 0, 30}, NSumTerms -> j, 
        EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[n]]][[2, 1]]}, {j, 15, 
     35}]) // MatrixForm`